# viewWillAppear not getting called for detailView of UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am experimenting with the splitViewController, introduced for iPads and am stuck at a point. I have a button on my detail view of the splitViewController, clicking on which a modal view opens. Now I want to change the positoning of UI controls on the detail view when the modal view gets dissmissed.

A pretty obvious way of doing this would be to catch the view transition in the ViewWillAppear method of the detailView. But it's not being called in this case. I remember facing the same problem in tabBarController where [tabBarController viewWillAppear:animated] was needed to be set before viewWillAppear of views in each tab item got called. I tried doing this with the splitViewController as well, but this doesn't seem to to work.

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the positioning is required due to an action that occurred in the modal view, you should use an explicit delegate callback. That will allow you to clearly specify the control flow and resulting behaviour of your app.

You should then define a protocol that has specific methods that carry pertinent information about the action taken. When the action occurs in the modal, perform the protocol method on the delegate, and it can react to that event (for you it seems to be a re-layout of button positioning).

To get an idea of the methods that are abstract enough to handle generic modal behaviour, look at `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. Here the delegate will get an `alertViewCancel:` message when the user decides to take no action, or `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` when they selected one of the options presented to them.

That is a good start for how to define the protocol.

If you need a many view controllers to react to the action taken in the modal, say a Sign In modal, then a better mechanism is notifications.